# How to check if a customer's birthday has passed for the ongoing year?

Tags: oracle

I have a table storing information about customers which includes a column "dateofbirth". I need to fetch those customers whose birthday has passed for the ongoing year (2015). How can I extract both date and month and compare it with system date and month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`EXTRACT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm):

```
SELECT *
FROM   CUSTOMERS
WHERE  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM dateofbirth ) < EXTRACT( MONTH FROM SYSDATE )
OR     (   EXTRACT( MONTH FROM dateofbirth ) = EXTRACT( MONTH FROM SYSDATE )
       AND EXTRACT( DAY FROM dateofbirth )   <= EXTRACT( DAY FROM SYSDATE ) )
```

or you can use `TO_CHAR` with the [`MMDD`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA) day of year format

```
SELECT *
FROM   CUSTOMERS
WHERE  TO_CHAR( dateofbirth, 'MMDD' ) <= TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'MMDD' )
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I am currently using EXTRACT to get what I need

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(to_date('27-01-1966','DD-MM-YYYY'),'MMDD'),to_char(sysdate,'MMDD'),
CASE WHEN to_char(to_date('27-01-1966','DD-MM-YYYY'),'MMDD') > to_char(sysdate,'MMDD')
     THEN 'No'
     ELSE 'Yes'
END
from dual;
```

So

```
WHERE to_char(dateofbirth,'MMDD') < to_char(sysdate,'MMDD')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggested the following solution

```
SELECT
  name,
  TO_CHAR(dob,'mm') MONTH,
  TO_CHAR(dob,'dd') DAY
FROM
  target_table
WHERE
  TO_CHAR(sysdate,'yyyy') =2015
AND
  (
    to_number(TO_CHAR(dob,'mm'))<to_number(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'mm'))
  OR
    (
      TO_CHAR(dob,'mm')   =TO_CHAR(sysdate,'mm')
    AND TO_CHAR(dob,'dd')<=TO_CHAR(sysdate,'dd')
    )
  );
```

i had written code based on my table data......
dob=date of birth

tartget_table= required table